# Laravel 5.7 email verification error, route [verification.verify] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am trying to implement email verification in Laravel 5.7. I have implemented `MustVerifyEmail` on `User` model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail 
{ 
}
```

But after registration I got this error `Route [verification.verify] not defined`.

What I am missing in this? Please guide?

Answer (score 4):

What really happens:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {

(['auth:sanctum', 'verified']
```

when passing two arguments of laravel one of authentication and the other of verification of mail. It says: it is authenticated.  and verified  ok response: Respond that the user in the table: User email_verified_at is not registered on the email activation date, that is, it has not told me that the email exists. ps passes an exception for that there is a page that you must active as a response to this ... that is, as a response to this ...
Your email is not verified even if the page is created either in vue on blade or in limewire in the auth folder.

in App\Models\User search

```
 // use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

active:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

eh implements

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

now many things are missing ..
We verify that kernel is active the following parameters :

in route App\Http\Kernel.php

```
// 'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
```

change:

```
'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
```

in the folder Config:
config\fortify.php
this:

```
    // Features::emailVerification(),
```

it

```
    Features::emailVerification(),
```

And the most important of this authentication hell .. the routes:
You can do the different types of routes you choose ... but one according to your resources or project.

basic:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->middleware('verified')->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

a little adrenaline:

```
Route::group(["middleware" => ['auth:sanctum','verified']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
        // return "hola william";
    })->name('dashboard');
    //aca puedes segir colocando las paginas o recursos que quieres cargar mientras en usuario este autenticado y verificado...
});
```

where does the error come from:
Route [verification.verify] not defined

this route/file..
vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailsVerified.php

function:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
{
    if (! $request->user() ||
        ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
        ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
        return $request->expectsJson()
                ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                : Redirect::guest(URL::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

linea:

```
: Redirect::guest(URL::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice'));
```

Thank you and success in your projects with laravel. and sorry if I wrote something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In `routes/web.php` file, add following piece of code:

```php
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification#verification-routing

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

It will clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

In routes/web.php ensure
`Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`
Then run :

```
php artisan route:cache
```

to clear cached routed and update incoming changes

Answer (score 0):

You can remove **'verified'** middleware, for example:

```
<?php

Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])
    ->group(function(){

     ...

});

?>
```

Try it, should solve the problem